# How do I get if stamens to run in Java 11?

Tags: if-statement, input, java.util.scanner

I am new to Java 11. I have a little experience with Java 8, but I am pretty much re-learning everything. I was trying to prompt for a Username and then password if the username was correct but Main won't run anything in the if statement. It asks for the username and then after typing the username whether wrong or right the program just ends. Cant figure this out. I tried changing variables and declaring them differently but I just started making it worse.[This picture shows the code for my program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXCK5.png)

Comment: You should post the code directly in the question. Second, Strings are objects in Java, so you can’t compare two Strings with `==` since that will compare memory addresses instead of the content of your strings. If you want to compare Strings, you can use the isEqual method of the String class.

Comment: Hi @Citex101, welcome to StackOverflow. Please post the code formatted in your post as text (it should be as easy as copy/pasting it and then formatting it in your question) rather than linking to a screenshot. This helps others work with your code easier in order to answer your question. Also, I believe you meant "statement" in your question title.